# How to add up values in all cells in a given range

Tags: codenameone

[image]

I need help, I have that table as seen in the image. The first column is not editable and the second column, a user can input figures as he wants. So my question is, how do I calculate the summation of all the rows in column 2 and enter them in the last row of the second column?

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this by implementing this 100% in the model:

```
String[] TITLES = {"Denomination", "Amounts"};
DefaultTableModel tm = new DefaultTableModel(TITLES, new Object[0][]) {
    @Override
    public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int column) {
        // can only edit right column can't edit last row
        return column == 1 && row < getRowCount() - 1;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getValueAt(int row, int column) {
        // if this is the last row second second column so we calculate the total
        if(row == getRowCount() - 1 && column == 1) {
            double total = 0;
            for(int iter = 0 ; iter < getRowCount() - 1 ; iter++) {
                try {
                    double dvalue = Util.toDoubleValue(super.getValueAt(row, column));
                    total += dvalue;
                } catch(IllegalArgumentException err) {
                    // validation warning/message...
                }
            }
            return total;
        }
        return super.getValueAt(row, column);
    }
};
tm.addRow(50000.0, null);
tm.addRow(10000.0, null);
// ...
tm.addRow("Total", null);
```